# error CS0103: The name 'DebugDisplayString' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

While debugging through a Monogame program I was noticing some weird behaviors in my code.

Whenever I hovered over a XNA Point, I would get the following error instead of seeing the value of the XNA Point.

error CS0103: The name 'DebugDisplayString' does not exist in the current context

[image: Visual Debug]

I printed the value of the point via the ToString(), and the result was empty AKA "".

Here is my test that I showed in the screenshot:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point point = new Point(3, 1);
    }
```

This started to happen recently.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `Point` a class or structure you made or is it from `System.Drawing`?

Comment: @JuanR It is from Microsoft.XNA.Framework, a component of the MonoGame library.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be referencing the Portable Class Library version of MonoGame in this project would you?

Comment: @CraftworkGames Yes, Yes I am. Is that not the proper one to reference for a program?

Comment: @CraftworkGames Switching to a non PCL version fixed it. If you make that an answer, I'll give you credit/accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you're referencing the PCL version of MonoGame.

The reason is that the PCL uses the [bait and switch](https://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) technique so the DLL doesn't actually contain an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Point` class is using the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute and implementing a property to provide the string representation as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute).

From the [MonoGame.Framework source](https://github.com/labnation/MonoGame/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Point.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Describes a 2D-point.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebugDisplayString,nq}")]
public struct Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
    /// Other code here
    internal string DebugDisplayString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat(
                this.X.ToString(), "  ",
                this.Y.ToString()
        );
    }
}
```

It looks like something happens every so often where the compiler is unable to work with this attribute properly.

Try cleaning your solution and rebuilding. It has fixed the issue for [others](http://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-error-vector2-does-not-work/10404/3).

Comment: @JaunR Good educated guess, yet one problem: When I output the X and Y values of the point, it is not 3, 1 like it should be. It is 0, 0. I wonder if this error message is just a symptom of a deeper problem.

Comment: @SneakyTactician3: True. Are you sure you don't have your own `Point` class defined somewhere? Are you positive it's using the XNA one?

Comment: I'm certain it's the XNA one. All of my point classes are called different things, and when I go to definition it goes to the XNA point.

Comment: craftworkgames's question led me to fixing it by installing a platform specific package, not the portable one.